# Socket programming to control the number of clients

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sockets

I m developing a C# database application. I used SQL Server 2005 as back end and C# .NET 2010 as front end.

My application is installed on each client machine. When database is updated all clients of my system get notified By SQL Server Event Dependency technique.

But now I want to control the number of clients connected to server. That is I only want to give access to 3 clients. For that, I want to add some client/Server code in my application using socket programming.

Please guide me on this issue.

Comment: It's way not trivial to do this correctly, and SQL Server probably has server-side settings/configuration for limiting number of clients. I.e. wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

From the [SqlDependency Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) on MSDN:

*SqlDependency was designed to be used in ASP.NET or middle-tier services where there is a relatively small number of servers having dependencies active against the database. **It was not designed for use in client applications**, where hundreds or thousands of client computers would have SqlDependency objects set up for a single database server. If you are developing an application where you need reliable sub-second notifications when data changes, review the sections Planning an Efficient Query Notifications Strategy and Alternatives to Query Notifications in the [Planning for Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187528.aspx) topic in SQL Server Books Online.*

In your particular scenario, I guess it would be a good idea to have a middle layer server which manages the client machines and which will use the `SQLDependency` to be notified by the changes in the database. Then, it will push notifications to batches of *n* client machines, following the logic you expect.

Comment: Sorry for late. But I just want socket programming code which controls the number of clients connected to server.Means server application that is totally different from main client application.My client application have some code which first connect to server application first.Then server application will count the client number. if it is greater than 3 then it will stop socket to accept new client.And my client application will stop running.